# Extract and join emails from array in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

In Power Automate. I used parse to read the get items from SharePoint list and I have taken Compose to see result.

I got result as:

```
[
      "i:0#.f|membership|abc.xyz@hhh.com",
      "i:0#.f|membership|rty.jkh@hhh.com"
]
```

But I want result as **abc.xyz@hhh.com;rty.jkh@hhh.com**

Please help how can I extract them and combine.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this ...

[image: Flow]

###### Initialize Combined Emails

This will contain the concatenated string of emails.  It's temporary until the end where I set the `Result` variable.

###### Append to Combined Emails

The expression here is ...

```
split(string(item()), '|')[2]
```

Take note of the semi-colon before the expression.

###### Initialize Result

You can do what you want here for a variable name, the important part is the expression.

```
substring(variables('Combined Emails'), 1)
```

This is the end result ...

[image: Result]